# required a dedicated node on kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, nodes

i need to isolate dedicated node for monitoring on our Kubernetes cluster anybody know what is the best practise for that?so that it is not impacted by auto scaling

Comment: Where are u running the cluster ? public cloud or bare matal? What does the auto scaling?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be achieved, that's where [Labels and Selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) come in handy.

You can label your nodes with key/value pairs, in-order to isolate your nodes based on behaviour of your application, [Node isoloation/restriction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/).

There are several ways one can label their nodes. But this the common and simplest example.

```
kubectl label nodes <node-name> <label-key>=<label-value>

Eg: kubectl label nodes k8-node-101 instance-type=monitoring
```

And in your deployment make sure you add the nodeSelector, something like this.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: monitoring-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mon-test
      image: "cr.mycompany.io/monitoring:v0.1"
  nodeSelector:
    instance-type: monitoring
```

This is one example on how you can isolate your node for specific needs or specific project purposes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: your solution won't work. Needs to be a separate node-pool. Otherwise the autoscaler can kill that node.

Comment: thanks alot i was thinking of another approach like having only one node to do only monitoring without impact of anything else or influence form autoscaler but looks its not actually doable as per my thought ..